# React Pass params to class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

currently in a project I'm working on there is a const for the page header that brings in parameters and uses the information:

```
    interface UserProps {
  user?: {
    name: string,
    image: string
  },
  loading?: boolean,
  error?: Error,
  theme: Object,
}

const Header = CurrentUser(({ user, loading, error, theme }: UserProps) => {
```

Specifically, I would like to user the user parameter that is passed.  I have a Component (class not a constant) that I would like to be able to also access user from the page, how would I get this value into the class?

```
class Registration extends React.Component {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

You would just want to pass the `user` prop to your Registration component:

`<Registration user={user} />`

You could then access it on the `props` property on the Registration class:

```
class Registration extends React.Component {
  // ... some stuff
  doSomethingWithUser(){
    const { user } = this.props;
    //or
    const user = this.props.user;
  }
}
```